# fetch data from API n times and then convert it into a single pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this small python script in which i'm fetching cryptocurrency exchange rate data every second.Now I want to stop after fetching data lets say 100 times and then convert all those data into a single dataframe. Also is scheduler the right way to do this?If no then what else should I be using?

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import sched, time

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
def my_function(sc): 
    data = requests.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=BTC,USD,EUR").json()
    print(data)
    s.enter(1, 1, my_function, (sc,))
s.enter(1, 1, my_function, (s,))
s.run()
```

Comment: Hi @klaptor, sorry I did not understand the part "Now I want to stop after fetching data lets say 100 times". Do you want to pause the main script execution for 100 secs after the whole data is fetched? and convert the data to a dataframe in a separate thread during that time?

Comment: so I want to stop the script after executing it 100 times and convert the fetched  data into a single dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import time
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from pandas import DataFrame

eur_collection = []
usd_collection = []
btc_collection = []

for i in range(100):
    print("Request {}".format(i))
    data = requests.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=BTC,USD,EUR").json()
    eur_collection.append(data["EUR"])
    usd_collection.append(data["USD"])
    btc_collection.append(data["BTC"])
    time.sleep(0.01)

dframe = DataFrame({
    'eur': eur_collection, 
    'usd': usd_collection, 
    'btc': btc_collection
})

dframe.plot()

plt.show()
```

Comment: @klaptor is this what you needed?

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I wanted.So, we dont need to use scheduler, i see...